# Show product items where no specific orders in a specific time frame

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three tables:

- ProductItems
- OrderItems
- Orders

The tables have the following associations:

`OrderItem` belongs to `Order`.
`OrderItem` belongs to `ProductItem`.

`Order` <- `OrderItem` -> `ProductItem`

The order table has a `delivery_date` and a `pick_up_date` column.

I want to get the `ProductItems` that have **no** orders in a specific time frame.

I tried it with this query but it still returns the `ProductItems` if they were there were `Orders` in the past or are in the future:

```
SELECT
    "product_items".*,
    "orders".*
    FROM
        "product_items"
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
            "order_items" ON "order_items"."product_item_id" = "product_items"."id"
            LEFT OUTER JOIN
                "orders" ON "orders"."id" = "order_items"."order_id"
    WHERE
        (
            '2017-10-24' < orders.delivery_date OR
            orders.pick_up_date < '2017-10-23' OR
            orders.id IS NULL
        )
```

The problem with that query is that it excludes product items that are in this specific timeframe. But since product items can be in multiple orders this won't work since the same product items that would be unavailable in the specified time frame can be in other orders that are not in this time frame. So they are still returned.

Is there a way to get just the product items in that specific time frames and exclude all product items where orders are present?

Something like this:

```
SELECT ALL PRODUCT ITEMS THAT HAVE NO ORDERS BETWEEN DELIVERY DATE AND PICK UP DATE
```

I use Postgres as database engine.

I've added an SQLFiddle example [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/abfe8/20).

I'm sitting on this problem since 6 hours now. Every help is appreciated.

Comment: please add sample data

Answer (score 0):

add time frame condition in `left join` instead of `where`

something like this

```
SELECT product_items.*,
orders.*
FROM product_items
LEFT OUTER JOIN order_items 
ON order_items.product_item_id = product_items.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN orders 
ON orders.id = order_items.order_id
AND ( '2017-10-24' < orders.delivery_date
    OR orders.pick_up_date < '2017-10-23' )
WHERE orders.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

If you could provide some sample data so I could recreate the DB and do some tests I'd gladly provide a more accurate solution.
In the meanwhile, give this a try

```
SELECT
"product_items".*,
"orders".*
FROM
    "product_items"
    INNER JOIN
        "order_items" ON "order_items"."product_item_id" = "product_items"."id"
    INNER JOIN
        "orders" ON "orders"."id" = "order_items"."order_id"
WHERE
    (
        product_items.id not in (orders_items.product_item_id) AND
        (whatevertimeframe you'd want)
    )
```

Comment: I've added an example [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/abfe8/20). The query shouldn't return any record. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
SELECT
    product_items.*
FROM
    product_items
    Inner  JOIN order_items 
        ON order_items.product_item_id = product_items.id
    Inner  JOIN orders 
        ON orders.id = order_items.order_id

    WHERE
       (
('2017-11-23' <= orders.delivery_date AND orders.delivery_date <= '2017-11-25') OR
('2017-11-23' <= orders.pick_up_date AND orders.pick_up_date <= '2017-11-25')
        )
```